# Colocar Progressbar dentro de uma celua JQGRID

Tags: jquery, html5, jqgrid

Como Coloco o **Progressbar** dentro da ultima coluna de acordo com o Tempo Percorrido?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var grid1 = $("#jqGridRiscoAcao").jqGrid({
    url: '/Qualidade/RiscoAcao/Listar',
     datatype: 'json',
     mtype: 'GET',

     postData: {
         IdRisco: 
         function ()
         { 
              var kwGrid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
              var ret = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getRowData', kwGrid);
              var retorno = 0;
              if (kwGrid != null){
                   retorno = ret['Id'];                                             
              }
               return retorno; 
            },
     },
     colModel: [
          { label: 'Id', name: 'Id', width: 30 , hidden: true},
         // { label: 'Ações Adicionais', name: 'Acoes_Adicionais', width: 180, align: 'center' },      
          {
              label: 'Inicio', name: 'Data_Inicio', width: 100, align: 'center', formatter: "date",
              formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y" }
          },
          {
              label: 'Data Final', name: 'Data_Final', width: 100, align: 'center', formatter: "date",
              formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y" }
          },
          { label: 'Tempo Pecorrido %', name: 'Porcentagem', width: 140,align: 'center' },


     ],

     viewrecords: true,
     rowNum: 20,
     rowList: [20, 40, 100],
     height: "auto",
     //height: 400,
     emptyrecords: "Nenhuma Medicao",
     loadtext: "Buscando e carregando...",
     //rowNum: 20,
     pager: "#jqGridRiscoAcaoPager",
     loadonce: true

 });
```